# How do I determine if the row has been inserted?

Tags: python, sqlite

When using sqlite3 for python, how do I determine if a row has been successfully inserted into a table? e.g.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('sample text')")

c.commit()
c.close()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If no exception was thrown when calling `execute()` or `commit()`, it was inserted when you called `commit()`.

Committing a transaction successfully is a guarantee from the database layer that the insert was written to disk.

Comment: So would there be some exception that may be raised from commit? For example, if commit failed then I can put something like "Row was not added"

Comment: Exactly. You could catch `sqlite3.Error` for that.

Answer (score 2):

you can get all the rows and see if its in there with:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

But SQLite will give you an error message if it didnt work.

Comment: What if there had been inserts before? The select will return rows, and not give you an error, but the inserts could still have failed.

Comment: The select will return all rows. And you double check if the row you just inserted is there.

Comment: That'll get tedious fast with a large number of rows. You don't need to do this at all; inserts either succeed or an exception is raised. Committing either succeeds or an exception is raised.

Comment: I konw, thats just if he isn't sure his inserts are working, and he wants to see it with his eyes to make sure. As I said in the answer: `But SQLite will give you an error message if it didnt work.`

Answer (score 1):

you can `count()` rows before inserting and after inserting.

Comment: Yet, if you do not commit, the insert will be discarded again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to have an error message:

```
    try:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('sample text')")
     except sqlite3.OperationalError, msg:
        print msg
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the commit on `connection made`(db selected which is `conn`) not on `cursor`.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('sample text')")
#commit the changes to db   
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First You should do the commit on the connection object not the cursor i.e
`conn.commit()` not `c.commit()`

Then you can examine `lastrowid` on the cursor to determine if the insert was successful after `conn.commit()`

`c.lastrowid`